# Jquery .Text not working in firefox 10

Tags: jquery

Am trying to get the  `Text(Title)` of below code

`<h6 id="test">Title</h6>`

using JQUERY `$(test).text()`

It is not working in Firefox 10 version and it working else where.

Do i need to change anything ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `#` to select elements with an HTML `id` attribute matching the value as described in the [CSS Selectors documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors).

So use:

```
$('#test').text()
   ^
  add a # here
```

Comment: Please don't use txtspk on SO, you presumably have a keyboard.

Comment: @Jamiec i did not understand .Please can u explain

Comment: What is txtspk you are saying

Comment: `I` not `i`. `you` not `u`. Write full words, using txtspk does not look professional.

Comment: Oh the irony of that response.

Comment: Also, please explain what the problem is and why your answer fixes it

Comment: "You need to add a `#` to select elements with an HTML `id` attribute matching that value as per <link to CSS selector documentation>. The OP missed this off the selector, therefore unless `test` was a variable it would generate a JavaScript error" **is** explaining what and why. Your "Use id as selector" does not really explain anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#test").text()
```

Instead of

```
$(test).text()
```