# Jquery working only for first iteration

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-applications

So I am trying to output a dynamically populated dropdown through jquery. The problem is that it just works for one iteration. The script -

```
<script> $(function() 
        {
            $("#projects").change(function() {   
            $("#tasks").load("getdata.php?choice=" + $("#projects").val());
            });       
        });           //getdata.php queries data and echoes <option>
                      //#projects -> <select> id and #tasks->options id
    </script>
```

I know it has something to do with introducing each there, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

This is the div where that is being looped -

```
foreach($days as $key=>$day)         //inside <select  id="projects">
{
    echo '<td align="center" width="65">
            <div>'.$day.'<br><input name="hours" type="text" size="2" placeholder="hours">
                <select id="tasks">
                    <option>Select a Project First</option>
                </select>
            </div>
          </td>';
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add all of the relevant HTML. I would like to see the `#tasks` and `#projects` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this one out with a friends help. 
Firstly, a very fundamental mistake of mine  -

Since `<select id="tasks">` field is being looped over for display it is more viable to change id to class.

After that its just comes to changing the `#tasks` to `.tasks` and the jscript does the work.

Otherwise each() can also be used to achieve the result like this -

```
$(".tasks").each(function() 
{
      $(this).(load)("getdata.php?choice=" + $("#projects").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .on() for the elements which will come dynamically.

```
 $(document).on('change','#projects',function(){
   //code here
 });
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help anyone understand what the problem and solution are. Remember [our conversation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16809465/637889) a few days ago?

Comment: @andyb sorry.Actually friend called me.So in hurry i posted like that

Comment: Tried still one iteration :\

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as $("#projects").change(function()  what I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Return from php file will change  content of #task

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.#projects').change(function(){
        var getdata = 'getdata.php?choice='+$("#projects").val();
        alert(getdata);
        $('#tasks').load(getdata);
    });
})
```

Comment: Tried this, still one iteration. I don't know where I am going wrong :|

Comment: hi, after changes on select you need to change  value of #task is it so  ? are you getting any error after changes? or you want to reload #project also

Comment: yes exactly, after changes to project tasks are loaded. I am getting absolutely no errors It works fine but just for onr iteration. If you see above I have a foreach loop displaying the output. The output comes out finr but the jquery works only on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

you need to refresh the dropdown list after you dynamicaaly appen val

---

```
//refresh value         
$('select').selectmenu('refresh');

//refresh and force rebuild
$('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```